# Change length of column of table which have dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a table named Contacts with column Title varchar(50) . Now in the middle of development I want to change the length to varchar(100) of field Title  .At the moment table Contacts has over 25 dependencies (other tables, views functions).
When I run following sql statement in sql server 2008 . I  am getting errors.

```
ALTER TABLE [Contacts ] ALTER COLUMN [Title ] varchar(100)
```

Error Like

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The object 'Contacts_title' is dependent on column 'title'.
```

And more.

Comment: have you checked http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816755

Comment: Try doing the change with SSMS designer. I would rarely suggest that, but in case like this it will generate a script to drop and re-create the dependent objects (constraints, indexes).

Answer (score 1):

you have to drop are recreate the constrains on the `Contact` table to do that or (sometime not really recommended ) you can temporary disable the constrain, alter the length and enable them again

```
--disable all constraints for the Sales.SalesOrderHeader table 
ALTER TABLE [yourtable] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL  

--do your stuff

--do something  --enable all constraints for the Sales.SalesOrderHeader table 
ALTER TABLE [yourtable] CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the dependence, and then create it again.

Comment: Rodrigo I know this, but is there any sql statement do this